# What does a gray Vee icon mean in TortoiseSvn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, icons

I have a gray Checkbox or 'vee' icon next to a XSL file.
It is identical to the usual 'green vee' that appears next to versioned files.

What do it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [TortoiseSVN help](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html):

[image]

> If you have set the svn:needs-lock
>   property on a file, Subversion makes
>   that file read-only until you get a
>   lock on that file. Such files have
>   this overlay to indicate that you have
>   to get a lock first before you can
>   edit that file.

Comment: Image link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 2):

if by "Vee" you mean Check mark. then the Grey Check Mark means the file is marked as Read Only.

You can see all the icon overlays in the Tortoise SVN Settings.

```
 Right Click Explorer
> Tortoise SVN
> Setttings
> Icon Overlay
> Icon Set
```

Answer (score 0):

From the help:

> The Needs Lock overlay is used to indicate when a file has the svn:needs-lock property set. For working copies which were created using Subversion 1.4.0 and later, the svn:needs-lock status is cached locally by Subversion and this is used to determine when to show this overlay. For working copies which are in pre-1.4.x format, TortoiseSVN shows this overlay when the file has read-only status. Note that Subversion automatically upgrades working copies when you update them, although the caching of the svn:needs-lock property may not happen until the file itself is updated.